# MS Access Import to Excel Unable to Connect

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have a MS Access database file that is hosted on a website that I cannot post here for security purposes.  I am trying to import tables from this database to an Excel file.  I am using both Excel and Access 2016. In Excel, I click on Data->New Query->From Database->MS Access.  I post my link to my exact database file on the website and then I get this error.

```
Details: "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue? I browsed the forums for an answer but nothing seems to be exactly what I am experiencing.

Comment: Err... What are you doing? You can't connect Excel to an Access database that's not on your computer or a network drive

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth  oh boy, you cant? what would be the best approach then because I thought you could connect to an access database that was not local.

Comment: Use a web-based database? Almost every SQL database can work, just not Access or SQLite.